# How to remove choppiness in Scroller on Playbook?

Tags: apache-flex, blackberry-playbook, scroller, flex4.5

After deploying the Flex 4.5 Spark Scroller control to a Playbook, the default result is choppy/jittery scrolling and no spring at the top and bottom of the scrolling.

Is there a way to change this behavior to a normal smooth touch scrolling with start and end springiness?

Answer (score 1):

Flex doesn't have 'springy' components, but the [Playbook's Air library](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/tablet/adobe.jsp) might have them.  If you want to have that feature, you'll have to extend your component and add it in.  As for the jitteriness, I can't say I've seen the same thing.  I'd look closely at your code to make it as efficient as possible.

Comment: I'm fairly sure the Flex mobile components that use the scroller have a springy / bounce effect at the ends. I'm using them in my lists. This is as of v.4.5

Comment: Ah right, I remember reading something about the mobile components in 4.5 to have the same experience as whatever platform you're aiming for.  Make sure you're compiling for that specific platform and not just doing a general air compile.

Answer (score 0):

The "springiness" that you are looking for doesn't come until AIR SDK 2.6, which will not work with the Playbook as of yet. It does work very well for Android though.

With that being said, have you tried using a list control? What type of content are you trying to scroll?